# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'search' while convering pyx file to py files

Tags: cython, python-3.4

I have created a setup.py file which contains the following code

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext= Extension("helloworld", sources=["helloworld.pyx"])
setup(ext_modules =[ext],
      cmdclass={'build_ext':build_ext})
```

However when i tried the command: python setup.py build_ext --inplace
an attributed error was given. 
The compilation output was:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from distutils.core import setup   File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 16, in 
>       from distutils.dist import Distribution   File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 7, in 
>       import sys, os, re   File "C:\Users\Payal Singh\Desktop\python all\re.py", line 4, in 
>       match=re.search(r'([\w\d.*]+)@([\w.*]+)',str) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'search'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have named your file "re.py" the same as python's regular expression module "re". Importing "re" imports a local module.